# Disabled scrolling by pressing spacebar, Then how to enable white spaces in textarea and ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have disabled scrolling by pressing spacebar using code
in-line(434)

And I use code in-line(427-432) to play/pause video by pressing spacebar anywhere in body.

// So how to enable white-spaces in textarea?

And how to disable playing/pausing video by pressing spacebar in textarea? //

I have tried code in-line(433) to enable white-spaces in textarea but it doesn't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEOTa.jpg

427-432:

`Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
get: function() {`

`return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2); } });`

`$("body").on("keydown", function(e) {  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
if (document.querySelector("video").playing) {
$("video")[0].pause(); } else {
$("video")[0].play(); } } });`

433:

`$("#comment").on("keydown", function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 32) { return true; } });`

434:

`$(document).keydown(function(e) { if (e.which == 32) { return false; } });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `document` listener, only `return false` if the `target` of the event is not a `textarea`:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 32 && e.target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA') {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Or, to additionally permit spaces in `input`s:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 32 && !['TEXTAREA', 'INPUT'].includes(e.target.tagName)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<input>
```